# Storing multiple data with same keys in a file and getting values from shell Script?

Tags: java, bash, shell, properties

I am getting output from json like dis,

```
{user=xxx, ip=xxxxx},   
{user=yyy, ip=yyyyy} etc .
```

I stored this data in properties file (to access this info from shell Script).

If I try to do that , It is coming like

```
        user=xxx
        ip=xxxxx
        user=yyy
        ip=yyyyy
```

But, In properties file key value should be unique right . If this is the case I can't access this data from properties file.

Actual requirement in script is I have to connect to the Ip using the corresponding user. The same has to be proceeded for every user .

Is there anyway to store the data other than properties file to access the values from shell Script?

Can anyone please guide me with this ?

Comment: How the values will be used in the shell script? Do you need only the IP address for a specific user? Is the `properties` file a must or you are free to store the data in a different format in the file?

Comment: I need to use both IP and User . I will use those values to connect to that IP using sshpass. No properties not must , can store in different format. The thing is have to access from Script .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want to access all users with their password from the file inside a shell script.

One possible solution could be to store in the properties file the user name as key and the password as value.

**properties file** `your.properties`

```
xxx=xxxxx
yyy=yyyyy
zzz=zzzzz
```

**shell script**

```
#!/bin/ksh
while read line.
do
  user=${line%%=*}
  ip=${line##*=}
  # example how to access the values
  printf "user: %s  IP: %s\n" "${user}" "${ip}"
done < your.properties
```

**output**

```
user: xxx  ip: xxxxx
user: yyy  ip: yyyyy
user: zzz  ip: zzzzz
```

**edit** If you have no control over the format of the properties file. A solution could be.

**properties file** `your.properties`

```
user=www
ip=wwwww
user=xxx
ip=xxxxx
user=yyy
ip=yyyyy
user=zzz
ip=zzzzz
```

**shell script**

```
#!/bin/sh
# the file input from file `your.properties` is redirected to filedescriptor 3
# to avoid problems with programs inside the loop which themself use `stdin`
# for reading input
while read user <&3; read ip <&3
do
  user=${user##*=}
  ip=${ip##*=}
  # example how to access the values
  printf "user: %s  ip: %s\n" "${user}" "${ip}"
done 3< your.properties
```

**output**

```
user: www  ip: wwwww
user: xxx  ip: xxxxx
user: yyy  ip: yyyyy
user: zzz  ip: zzzzz
```

Comment: My output in properties file itself is like `user: xxx  ip: xxxxx
user: yyy  ip: yyyyy
user: zzz  ip: zzzzz` , from this file I need to get User value and IP value. If I access from script , which user/ip it will consider ? That is the thing I am asking.

Comment: @Vidya You mean you have no control over the format of the properties file? If so check my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you . yeah it is iterating for 3 times before I gave sshpass.Now I included sshpass like following , 

`#!/bin/sh
while read user; read ip
do
  user=${user##*=}
  ip=${ip##*=}
        sshpass -p sas ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $user@$ip "mkdir vidya"
        

  printf "user: %s  ip: %s\n" "${user}" "${ip}"
done < xxx.properties
`
Output is :
user: xxx  ip: xxxxx

iterating only once. Did I miss anything here ?

Comment: @Vidya I have amended my second example. The properties file is now redirected to file descriptor 3 instead of stdin which is also used by sshpass. And so sshpass was reading the values from the properties file.

Comment: Thank you . Its working fine . Instead of 3(static number) , I can give variable name also right which is holding number !!!! reason is , Dont know exactly How many servers are there ..

Comment: @Vidya The number `3` is the filedescriptor to which the file content is redirected and used by `read`. It's not related to the number of entries in the file. To avoid confusion by others I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Working fine . sorry dnt know abt filedescriptor. Thank you so much for your clear explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right. Java property files are no choice for you because they will override old entries if same key arrives. But it is not hard to write something simular that can handle this situation.
Look at this class

```
public class SimpleStorage{
    private String[] entryNames;        // names of entries in one dataset
    private int amountEntries;          // amount of entries in one dataset
    private ArrayList<String[]> data;   // list of all datasets

    public SimpleStorage(String... _entryNames){
        entryNames = _entryNames;
        amountEntries = entryNames.length;
        data = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    public void put(String... dataSet){
        if(dataSet.length == amountEntries)
            data.add(dataSet);
        else
            System.out.println("Wrong amount of dataSet entries. " +
                "Should be " + amountEntries + ".");
        }
    public void save(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException{
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(filename, "UTF-8");
        // for all datasets
        for(String[] dataSet : data){
            // write all entries in form NAME=ENTRY
            for(int i = 0; i < amountEntries; i++){
                writer.println(entryNames[i] + "=" + dataSet[i]);       
            }
        }           
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
SimpleStorage ts = new SimpleStorage("user", "ip");
ts.put("xxx","xxxxx");
ts.put("yyy","yyyyy");
ts.put("zzz","zzzzz");
ts.save("output.txt");
```

And you will get an output File with this content:

```
user=xxx
ip=xxxxx
user=yyy
ip=yyyyy
user=zzz
ip=zzzzz
```

Comment: If that was the output , it will not possible to get correct value from script . For example , I will try to get info for user , which user it will consider from output.txt ? that is the problem I am facing . Is there any possibility to change key name before writing into properties/text file ?

Comment: I still dont get it. You want to fetch all the users corresponding to one ip. Or want all ips corresponding to one user?

Comment: User means username here , sry to mention wrongly . For one IP one Username will be der , may be same or diff . I need to get username and IP from the properties file / or any other file to connect to that IP using username in Script using sshpass(password will be same for all IPs . So no need to get that)